# is this a Qt qml bug for flags in Task Manager?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My application always run in background process, I take a long time to check why this occurs, because I think once my application runs, it should shows in Apps in task manager.
[image]

here is my test code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6 import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "red"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint }
```

Finally I find if I remove the

> flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

The app runs in Apps, but I can't set my app frameless and always on top. What can I do if I want to run my app in Apps in Task Manager?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get your application to show up as app, you need to have a window, that is not frameless. So your problem is easily to solve, by adding another window, that is not frameless, additionally to your frameless one:

```
Window {
    visible: true // No flags, but visible: Makes it appear as 'app'
    opacity: 0 // Makes the annoying popup at the beginning invisible
    Window {
        id: root
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        color: 'black'
        Row {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 2
            Button {
                text: 'flags'
                onClicked: console.log(root.flags.toString(2))
            }
            Button {
                text: 'close'
                onClicked: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```